# Вывод из общего времени таймера - часов, минут, секунд

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, время

Как отсюда вывести минуты отдельно? Это таймер обратного отсчета. Я получил часы , получил секунды. Но что на что нужно делить для получения остаточных минут?

```
b = currentTime - 86400
if b < tim:
    {(tim - b) // 3600}:непонятно сколько минут:{(tim - b) - ((tim - b) // 60 * 60)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найдите остаток от деления секунд на 60 (`секунды % 60`) - это и будут секунды. И теперь выполните целочисленное деление секунд на 60 (`секунды // 60`).

Comment: Cпасибо, работает

Comment: Не за что, всегда рад помочь)

Answer (score 0):

Называться это timeago вот реализация русского на LUA. Думаю с портированием на Py никаких проблем не должно быть.

```lua
local socket = require("socket")
local math = require("math")


function stuo(val, one, two, more)
  local n, t = val % 10, val % 100
  if t == 11 or t == 12
      or t == 13 or t == 14 then
    return more
  elseif n == 1 then
    return one
  elseif n == 2 or n == 3 or n == 4 then
    return two
  else
    return more
  end
end

function ago(of)
  local str, whole = "", 0
  if of >= 3600 then
    whole = math.floor(of/3600)
    of = of-whole*3600
    str = str .. tostring(whole) ..
      stuo(whole, " час ", " часа ", " часов ")
  end
  if of >= 60 or str ~= "" then
    whole = math.floor(of/60)
    of = of-whole*60
    str = str .. tostring(whole) ..
      stuo(whole, " минута ", " минуты ", " минут ")
  end
  return str .. tostring(of) ..
    stuo(of, " cекунда ", " секунды ", " секунд")
end

local n = 0
while true do
  n = n + 1
  print("прошло " .. ago(n))
  socket.sleep(1.0)
end
```

Comment: Хм, к сожалению это слишком весомый вариант. Во первых мне не нужно чтобы оно показывало сколько прошло времени. Мне нужно что бы при активации команды выводилось время сколько осталось до возможной активации новой команды. И это должно быть одной строкой